# Why is UnusedMember.Global ignoring certain public/internal properties?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

As we know, when R# finds type or member that is not used directly, it grays it out. It's normal that when we write new class, all fields are initially grayed out. That is due to `UnusedMember.Global` rule. Except, it doesn't apply to few names...

If type/member has name from some defined set, this rule will not mark it as invalid, and somehow decide that it is actually used, even when there are no methods in class, and class itself is not used anywhere (but it only applies to `public` and `internal`, `private` works as expected). Type of member doesn't seem to matter. Capitalization doesn't seem to matter either.

Words that I found to behave like this are: `Id`, `Guid`, `System`, `Configuration`, `Configurations`, `Name`, `Names`, `Service`, `Services`, `var` and all keywords that just point at class/struct, if written in other way than all lowercase (so `INT`, `Object`, `String` etc.) and their plural forms (these can be lowercase, so `ints`)

So lets take this class:

```
internal class ConfiguredService // Grayed out
{
    internal string RemoteSystem { get; } // Grayed out
    internal string LocalSystem { get; } // Grayed out
    internal string Configuration { get; } // Not grayed
    internal string ints { get; } // Not grayed
}
```

It doesn't look like a bug to me, it would be caught years ago as it's quite visible and trival to reproduce. But I cannot find any source that would explain why is it designed like this, and list words that take this behavior.

My version of Visual Studio is Professional 2017 15.8.5, and R# is in version 2018.1.2

Comment: Unable to reproduce with any of the following combinations: `VS Professional 2017 15.9.4 and ReSharper 2018.1.2`, `VS Professional 2017 15.9.4 and ReSharper 2018.3.1`, `VS Enterprise 2019 16.0.0 Preview 1.1 and ReSharper 2018.3.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have "solution wide analysis" (SWA) is off and "show unused non-private type members when solution-wide analysis is off" is "on" (both features you can turn on/off in menu ReSharper -> Options -> Code Inspection ->Settings).
When SWA is off usage analysis for non-private works in lightweight mode: it looks for files that contains the name of the typemember as text and if there are non a lot of files then looks for actual usages. But if there are a lot of files with required name then it does not check for actual usages and treats the typemember as "used". This heuristic causes false negatives on typememberы with popular names like you mentioned but allows ReSharper's daemon to work faster. With enabled SWA usage analysis is more precise and should not contain any false negatives